# How to get item price BEFORE discount from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item

Tags: price, model, discount

Magento CE 1.9.1.9

I'm in the process of modifying a custom module that gets item information form the Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item model when an order is placed. Currently I'm getting pricing information like this:

```
    'sell_price' => $this->_getBaseAmt('row_total', $item),
    'original_price' => $item->getOriginalPrice(),
```

I'm attempting to get either the discount amount *or* if possible, the price before discount. Here is an example of my attempt:

```
'price_before_discount' => $item->getPrice(),
```

But all I can ever seem to return is the sale price (aka "special price"). Can someone provide an example of the correct way to get this information? I need the original price of item that has been ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the object I have the original price in all of these:

```
$orderItem->getPriceInclTax();
$orderItem->getBasePriceInclTax();
$orderItem->getRowTotalInclTax();
$orderItem->getBaseRowTotalInclTax();
```

While these gets the discounted price:

```
$orderItem->getPrice();
$orderItem->getBasePrice();
$orderItem->getRowTotal();
$orderItem->getBaseRowTotal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution found on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368757/how-to-show-the-original-price-in-the-shopping-cart-in-magento

This will pull the non-discounted price in my scenario:

```
$item->getProduct()->getPrice(),
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if the product's price has changed this will give you the new price not the original price at time of purchase - which I believe it is not possible to reconstruct.

Comment: What about with a method like this? $this->_getBaseAmt('row_total', $item)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this information is not stored. In `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php` you have

```
        $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty());
        $item->setPrice($finalPrice)
            ->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->calcRowTotal();
```

which uses the final discounted, specially priced amount including potential tier/group pricing.

Your answer to look up the original product can work if the pricing doesn't change and you also need to be careful of catalog promotions. Depending on your requirements you might want to create an extension that saves the price information at the time the order is placed with the order item (you might even want to keep this in a separate product attribute (standard price for example).

Comment: This looks interesting. Trying it now!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Will keep trying. Getting this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFinalPrice() on a non-object

Comment: The code is quoted from https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php#L115 to highlight where this information is NOT stored. To implement what I suggested you would need to build out an extension that adds a new product attribute and a way to store this when converted from a quote to order in the database. Best of luck.